# What does "talking about the same things in the same manner no matter what" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a book which is about women and how to approach them. The writer said that after approaching women, they will:

> Some women will be so interested in you that they cannot stop talking, while some will be shyer or less open. Their initial reaction does not matter that much, as long as they stay where they are, and if they are smiling, they are obviously happy that you approached them. **You should be talking about the same things in the same manner no matter what**. The only difference really will be the pace of the conversation and how much effort you have to devote to making women feel comfortable enough to loosen up.

I don't understand the sentence "You should be talking about the same things in the same manner no matter what", especially the expression "no matter what", despite searching it on *oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com*. Can someone explain this sentence and the expression for me please? Thank you!

Comment: " ...despite searching it on oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com". You know how to scroll a page down, don't you? The definition is at the bottom (no matter who, what, where, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"[no matter what](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+matter+what)*** (happens)", is an idiomatic expression meaning:

> - in any event; without regard to what happens (in the future). *We'll be there on time, no matter what. No matter what happens, we'll still be friends*.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.)

- the author is saying that you should  talk freely without caring about possible consequences.